# Programming Pearls -- Column 1: Sorting unique numbers with bitfield

Tags: performance, sorting, rust, unix, bitset

I've implemented a simple program to sort an input of unique  numbers given as decimals on a separate line.  The idea is, since all numbers are unique, to use a (long) bitfield where a *1* on index *n* represents that the number *n* is in the sorted list.  The algorithm thus consists of these phases (as described in the book):

```
/* phase 1: initialize set to empty */
    for i = [0, n)
        bit[i] = 0
/* phase 2: insert present elements into the set */
    for each i in the input file
        bit[i] = 1
/* phase 3: write sorted output */
    for i = [0, n)
        if bit[i] == 1
            write i on the output file
```

In order to (re-)freshen my Rust, I chose to implement this in Rust, to be an efficient replacement for sort(1) when given the `-n` option, assuming unique input.  Thus the program can be called as:

```
$ bitfield # sorts stdin, writes to stdout
$ bitfield foo # sorts foo, writes to stdout
$ bitfield foo - bar # sorts foo, stdin, bar, writes to stdout
```

As with the exercise, I assume *n* (`MAXNUM`) to be *10,000,000*:

```rust
use std::io::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::env;

const MAXNUM: usize = 10_000_000;
const _MAXLINES: usize = 1_000_000;

fn fill(src: impl BufRead, bitfield: &mut[u8; MAXNUM >> 3]) -> Result<()> {
    for line in src.lines() {
        let num = line?.parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        if num > MAXNUM {
            return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "number too large!"));
        }

        bitfield[num >> 3] |= 1 << (num & 0b111);
    }

    return Ok(());
}

fn print_sorted(bitfield: &[u8; MAXNUM >> 3], dest: impl Write) -> Result<()> {
    let mut dest = BufWriter::new(dest);

    for (i, byte) in bitfield.iter().enumerate() {
        for bit in 0..=0b111 {
            if byte & (1 << bit) != 0 {
                write!(&mut dest, "{}\n", (i << 3) | bit)?;
            }
        }
    }

    return Ok(());
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut bitfield: [u8; MAXNUM >> 3] = [0; MAXNUM >> 3];

    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().skip(1).collect();
    if args.is_empty() {
        fill(stdin().lock(), &mut bitfield)?;
    }

    for arg in args {
        if arg == "-" {
            fill(stdin().lock(), &mut bitfield)?;
        } else {
            let f = match File::open(&arg) {
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("{}: {}", &arg, e);
                    continue;
                }
                Ok(f) => BufReader::new(f),
            };
            fill(f, &mut bitfield)?;
        }
    }
    print_sorted(&bitfield, stdout())?;

    return Ok(());
}
```

To test, I used GNU/shuf(1), time(1), and cmp(1):

```
$ shuf -i 1-10000000 -n 1000000 > foo
$ time ./target/release/bitsort foo > bar
0.19s user 0.03s system 97% cpu 0.221 total
$ time sort -n foo > bar2
1.56s user 0.06s system 291% cpu 0.556 total
$ cmp bar bar2
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `use` declarations

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::*;
```

That's a sneaky way to import `io::{Error, Result}`.  For the sake of
readability, it may be beneficial to spell out `io::` each time.  Also
see the Error handling section below.

`use` declarations can be condensed.  For example:

```rust
use std::{env, fs::File, io};
```

## Allocation

```
let args: Vec<_> = env::args().skip(1).collect();
```

This is an unnecessary allocation.  The `main` function can be
rewritten in terms of iterators using [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable):

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // ...

    let mut args = env::args().skip(1).peekable();

    if args.peek().is_none() {
        // read from stdin
    }

    for arg in args {
        // handle arg
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Error handling

Instead of unwrapping the result of `parse`, you can propagate the
error.

For a larger program, I would suggest using the [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/) crate
for error handling, which reduces a lot of boilerplate.

## Miscellaneous

Don't write `return Ok(());` at the end of a function — just use
`Ok(())`.

I think you meant `>=` here: `if num > MAXNUM`.

In `print_sorted`, you wrap the writer in a `BufWriter`.  What if the
writer is already buffered?  I would leave the decision to the caller.

You can use `let mut bitfield = [0_u8; MAXNUM >> 3];` for less
duplication.

Using a crate like [`bit-set`](https://docs.rs/bit-set/) might be good for readability.

Comment: Tyvm!  Regarding import, I do need a bit more (ErrorKind, stdin, stdout, BufRead, Write, BufReader, BufWriter) unfortunately.  I do like peek though, although it needs `args` to become mut then, as you did.  I now propagate the error and also used expressions instead of explicit returns.  I originally chose to use BufWriter, since I also used the BufRead trait and to be consistent.  I will keep bit-set in mind, when I have to "real work" programs.  Thanks again!